Why doesn't my Dell Wyse 5070 show a white LED light when powered on?
I just got a 2nd Wyse 5070 (a thin client). Unfortunately, this one has a weird issue: there is no white LED indicator when the machine is running.
It works just fine, no errors, everything is recognized (memory, SSD, network). Proxmox is preinstalled, so I just could test it completely.
Is there a BIOS setting or something that disables the white LED power indicator? I couldn't find anything there. Any ideas?

It’s probably just burned out given the device is from 2017.

As someone with multiple aging Dell devices from around the same timeframe, that used to have working LED indicator lights, I believe this is a wear/use issue, as Ramhound mentioned in a comment above.
The indicator lights appear to get dimmer over time, eventually going completely dark.
According to the user manual of your device, the power button is in a part combined with the speaker, and only requires two cables to be disconnected/reconnected. If you're able to find a replacement part, it should be an easy one to swap out. However, It looks like the machine is out of support, so you'd have to source a second-hand or refurbished part.

I've got one and assumed this was the case. Nice to know others have the same problem. Not going to do anything about it, just rather irritating.

@wjdp yeah it's not a big issue for me either. I'll figure out pretty quickly if the device is on or off :D
